# Can someone answer a question about centrifugal force and gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, centrifugal-force

I have a question! I’m doing a school project on centrifugal force and gravity.  I know that for every increase in speed, there is an expounding increase in pressure, which very quickly becomes some big math!

Am I correct in thinking that if the unit drawn below was spun from the top (assuming it was close enough to perfectly balanced, ie like the way engine parts are made to spin fast)  that the two weights would be pulled outward more and more, the faster it was spun?  Like at some point, it would overcome the weight of the larger ball hanging below and “lift” it as the chain folded? I’ve heard centrifugal force is way stronger than gravity, is this what they’re talking about?

(I’m not the best artist, hopefully you can decipher my drawing.  The middle part is hinged, so it can fold as it spins.  Also, the bearing on the bottom stops the other weight from spinning - so just the middle folding part actually spins.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You conceptualisation is all over the place. Pressure is not the correct word there. Your pictures and question make sense. Yes, it will move as you think it does. However, it is not from the weights being pulled outwards more; it will appear so, but it is the opposite: to keep up the spinning, you have to pull inwards with greater and greater forces, and at some point the weight in the middle is insufficient to pull them back at its lowest position, and so it moves upwards a little.

Comment: ok thank you... i'm still struggling with centrifugal force vs centripedal - its just easier to see in my mind the outward force.  I have just a couple more questions... 1, I'm assuming the chain would continue to lift (compress itself flat) to the point where it was spinning just below the motor, because centrifugal (or pedal) force wants to come to the middle of where the actual spinning is occuring, correct?

Comment: And my other question is, even with a weight of 100 pounds below, or even 1000, if the unit was spinning fast enough, thereby creating enough pulling force to compress the chain, it could theoretically pick up any weight, as long as the metal (chain) was strong enough?  Like theres no limit to centrifugal/centripedal force - it just gets stronger and stronger the faster something spins?  Thank you again!

Comment: It is not clear that you mean by the first question but it seems like yes. and yes.

Comment: Sorry, my concept was a little hard to explain without drawing it out - but I appreciate your responses! My final question is - with or without the weight, and because of the bearings, the motor spinning the hinge would only be spinning the couple pounds of the hinge unit itself... and so would not require a strong torque (ie a fairly small electeric engine)? This seems a simple way to move large amounts of weights with a smaller motor than would normally be required to simply dead lift the weight.  Using centrifugal force to outpower gravity...?

Comment: But I can't seem to get any traction on this idea.  Everyone thinks its crazy but I think it makes sense - thus my project..

Comment: It cannot work the way you think it works. Energy is conserved. The electric motor will have to be really really powerful just to get the system to start turning if the weights are heavy. There will be very strong friction at the top joint.

Comment: Centripetal and centrifugal forces are not fundamental forces like gravity and electromagnetism, thus it is inappropriate to make a comparison like: "centripetal force is stronger than gravity". Whether such a force can overcome gravity or not simply depends on how much energy you put in. On the other hand, electro forces can be said to be stronger than gravitaitonal.

Comment: Thank you for all your input! I appreciate the feedback. I am sure I use many of the wrong words, I'm not used to talking about all this.

Comment: I am trying to understand all this. I 3D printed a concept of the idea, it acts as imagined. Using a tiny, toy car motor, I have been able to "lift" 15 lbs already. This motor maybe could do this with lots of proper gearing, but it would take significant time. But this same action only requires a few seconds when spun? Regarding friction, I looked into thrust bearings with co-efficient ratings of .0015. The math suggests (per the company) it would take less than a 1/2HP to turn a 1lb total weight with 1000lb axial load on said bearing @3000rpm. Friction wont stop this.. so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Like others pointed out,you are confused between terms like pressure and force,here it is unnecessary to deal with pressure i.e. the force per unit area,while your overall intuition is somewhat correct,yes the 10lb ball would rise compared to its initial position.

**About your general idea on basis of the diagram:**

Your understanding is on the right track, and your initial and final diagrams show the general concept.

However, let's refine a few details. In the initial conditions, when the motor is off, the strings attached to the two 1lb balls would hang vertically, while the strings connecting the motor to the ball might have different arrangements based on their connection points.

In the final condition, when equilibrium is achieved, the 10lb ball would indeed lift above its initial position. The strings connecting it to the motor would undergo changes in their arrangements. However, the strings connecting the two 1lb balls would not be completely horizontal. They would be more inclined towards the horizontal axis compared to the initial conditions but not entirely horizontal. These strings need to provide both the required centripetal force and a vertical force to counteract gravity.

**Centrifugal vs Centripetal**:

It's important to note that centrifugal force is a pseudo force utilized when analyzing situations in a rotating frame of reference. The incline of the strings connecting the 1lb balls towards the horizontal axis is due to their inability to provide the necessary centripetal force initially, as they pull the balls vertically. As they incline more towards the horizontal axis they can now provide this required horizontal centripetal force and their tension increases to supply the required horizontal centripetal force and support the weight of 1lb balls against gravity.

The other two strings connecting the 10lb ball with the motor will also change their arrangement, becoming more horizontally inclined, and their tension will increase to balance both the centripetal forces and the weight of the ball.

Regarding your comment on lifting heavier weights with this setup, it's possible, but it would necessitate a higher power motor to maintain the same rotation speed as a setup with lighter weights.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for all your input!  I appreciate the feedback.  I am sure I use many of the wrong words, I'm not used to talking about all this.

Comment: I am trying to understand all this. I 3D printed a concept of the idea, it acts as imagined. Using a tiny, toy car motor, I have been able to "lift" 15 lbs already. This motor maybe could do this with lots of proper gearing, but it would take significant time. But this same action only requires a few seconds when spun? Regarding friction, I looked into thrust bearings with co-efficient ratings of .0015. The math suggests (per the company) it would take less than a 1/2HP to turn a 1lb total weight with 1000lb axial load on said bearing @3000rpm. Friction wont stop this.. so what am I missing?

Comment: Most toy car motors would typically max out at 25Watts,1/2HP is too out of range of a toy car motor and just to be clear theoretically every given weight would be lifted by a certain height(in case you get the system in rotation) irrespective of the loads connected to "hinges" laterally or the rpm.

Comment: Yes I understand.  This would be a scaled up version.  1000lbs would require more than a toy car motor.  My point is that it seems much more "work" can be done using this method than a traditional method.  The company Gravitricity makes electricity picking up weight and dropping it.  Do you really not think this is a more economical way to pick up weight considering the awesome bearings we are capable of manufacturing?  If not, why not exactly?  Where preciously in the figuring or math do you think I am going wrong?

Comment: Your current model isn't exactly a way of picking things up,it just lifts things upto a certain extent,its actually not very efficient as you end up needing energy to spin the whole system.